# Accessing system clipboard in J2ME (Sony Ericsson)

Tags: java-me, clipboard, copy-paste, sony

Recent mobile phones have a clipboard where text can be copied from one application to another (E.g. from address book to file manager). Is there an API for placing things on this clipboard?

I am targeting Sony Ericsson phones (including G705), so a Sony specific API would be acceptable if no portable API exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user might be able to manually copy/paste text between applications if you display a `javax.microedition.lcdui.Textbox` or a `javax.microedition.lcdui.Textfield` and you can obviously access the text in the objects in your own MIDlet but there is no proper clipboard API accessible from Java code in any of the current Sony-Ericsson JP8.x platforms, not even a proprietary one.

Comment: I have tried with the TextField and it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

JSR 75 API gives access to the file system and the PIM access. However am not sure if it is possible to access the clipboard

Comment: The JSR 75 specification is available at http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr075/index.html. Unfortunately it does not provide an API for accessing the clipboard.